# Example of mean independent variables but dependent still

Tags: correlation, mean, independence

Econometric textbooks often make the distinction between three types of independence:

1. Stochastic independence: $\mathrm{D}(u|x)=\mathrm{D}(u)$
2. Mean independence: $\mathrm{E}(u|x)=\mathrm{E}(u)$
3. Linear independence: $\mathrm{Cov}(u,x)=0$

with the one preceding being stronger and implying the subsequent. For instance, Wooldridge (2002, p.22) states:

> We also need to know how the notion of statistical independence relates to conditional expectations. If $u$ is a random variable independent of the random vector $x$,
> then $\mathrm{E}(u|x)=\mathrm{E}(u)$, so that if $\mathrm{E}(u)= 0$ and $u$ and $x$ are independent, then $\mathrm{E}(u|x) = 0$. The converse of this is not true: $\mathrm{E}(u|x)=\mathrm{E}(u)$ does not imply statistical independence between $u$ and $x$ (just as zero correlation between $u$ and $x$ does not imply independence).

It is easy to come with examples of uncorrelated random variables that are not (mean) independent. $Y=X^2$ is a classic one. Many questions on this site cover others (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188242/100369)).

What I'm struggling with is to think of an example of two variables which are mean independent but dependent more generally. I wonder whether this is merely a technical point or we are against a true possibility in science. I don't even know how to start to simulate an example of such joint distribution. Independent on mean but dependent on variance? Maybe something from finance? Any ideas on this?

Comment: Let $u\sim\mathcal{N}(0,x^2)$ for instance: that has constant mean but since the variance of $u$ depends on $x,$ $(x,u)$ is not independent. You can find many more examples by searching for posts about weak stationarity of time series. This one is easy to simulate in `R`: `u <- rnorm(1e3, 0, (x <- rnorm(1e3))^2);
plot(x, u)`

Comment: @whuber hahaha you went literal and introduce x into another moment. Evident my dear Watson... Does this even exist in practice? Will search what you suggest.

Comment: a finance example is any arch process.

Comment: @mlofton Something like: the value of stocks do not depend on the weather but the variability of stocks do?

Comment: that's exogenous dependence rather than model dependence.arch says that variability is related to past variability. there are many introductory explanations of arch on the net.

Comment: The null hypothesis of the [Welch t test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) is an important example of mean independence, linear independence, but not stochastic independence.

Comment: @whuber correlation seems to be positive though. Just tried seed 12345.

Comment: The correlation is zero.  Don't rely on the results of a single simulation.

Comment: @whuber Thanks. I think this Q is answered. Do you mind adding a short answer?